# Mouse multimedia buttons are not emitting events in `/dev/input/eventX`

Tags: linux, usb, mouse, hid

I have a mouse (Canyon CND-SGM14RGB) with multiple programmable buttons, half of them are set to be multimedia buttons.
Software for configuration is Windows-only, and those buttons work in Windows -- even without the special driver.

However in Linux only buttons mapped to standard mouse actions work (lmb, rmb, middle, forward/backward). Multimedia buttons do not work.

---

I have tried following diagnostic steps:

1. Launching `wev` (`xev` alternative for wayland) and pressing all the buttons:

   Regular buttons work, but multimedia do not.
2. Doing `cat /dev/input/eventX` and looking for new data:

   According to `/proc/bus/input/devices` there are two files associated with the mouse, one did emit garbage when doing regular mouse activities, and both were silent when pressing multimedia buttons.
3. Launching Wireshark and looking for mouse packets, I have found that:

   - Handshake (???) is sent from device 2.27.0 (bus 2, device 27, endpoint 0)
   - Regular mouse events (those that are emitted in the `/dev/input/eventX`) are sent from device 2.27.1
   - Multimedia button presses are sent from device 2.27.2.

Is there something that I can do to make those buttons work? I can provide Wireshark dump files if needed.

EDIT 1: `lsusb` output

```
Bus 002 Device 027: ID 258a:0027 SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x258a 
  idProduct          0x0027 
  bcdDevice            1.02
  iManufacturer           1 SINOWEALTH
  iProduct                2 Wired Gaming Mouse
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x003b
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              480mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      71
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     213
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

EDIT 2: relevant `libinput list-devices` output

```
Device:           SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event9
Group:            9
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse Keyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event10
Group:            9
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a
```

Comment: could you do two things: 1. find out the vendor id, product id pair `VID:PID`, as found as `ID 123a:f789` when running `lsusb` and looking for your mouse, 2. run `lsusb -v -d 123a:f789` with that VID:PID, and add the result to your question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller done.

Comment: cool! That EP2, the endpoint on which your multimedia button presses are emitted is a keyboard! Makes sense, kind of! It should also appear as such to libinput; hm. `sudo libinput list-devices` doesn't list it, does it?

Comment: `libinput list-devices` says that there is `/dev/input/event9`, which has `Capabilities: pointer`, and `event10`, with `Capabilities: keyboard`.

However, doing `cat /dev/input/event10` or `evtest /dev/input/event10` output nothing. `evtest` prints some information about the device, but no events.

Comment: I have added relevant `list-devices` output to the question.

Comment: huh! Strange! If libinput sees the device, the device does emit reports according to wireshark, but libinput doesn't report these, maybe something is wrong with these reports?? I honestly don't know!

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/1460840/906557

I don't now why, but it is working:

> With this particular mouse (and with many others I believe), you can bind additional buttons to any key combination, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow button</kbd>, with a Windows software, and then use those as custom shortcuts for the media in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

```
bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
```

Looks like the mouse is not using the normal USB HID protocol, but a separate *USB HID boot protocol*, which is handled by separate `usbkbd` and `usbmouse` kernel modules. The overwhelming majority of USB mice prefer the `hid` protocol instead, and some distributions might not even load the boot protocol driver for mice automatically.

Since the `usbhid` module normally claims all devices that identify as generic USB mouse and keyboard devices, you might have to explicitly prioritize the boot protocol driver for this mouse.

You could do this by creating e.g. a `/etc/modprobe.d/canyonmouse.conf` file with the following contents:

```
# Prioritize boot protocol for the multimedia keys of this mouse
install usbhid /sbin/modprobe usbkbd; /sbin/modprobe -i usbhid
alias usb:v258ap0027* usbkbd
```

After creating this file, you should update your initrd/initramfs file.

This will force the keyboard boot protocol module to load first before the `usbhid` module, giving it the chance to take control of the mouse (and specifically its "keyboard" interface) before the `usbhid` driver takes over.

I had to do the same thing to make a server with an AST2400-based remote management interface to respond to keystrokes over the web-based remote management connection: it turns out the remote management connection provides a virtual mouse and keyboard device to the server, both of which support the boot protocol only. For the mouse functions, this was not a problem, but apparently boot-protocol-only keyboards are such a rarity that there is not yet automatic support for them.

Since the requirement to use the HID boot protocols is pretty rare, some distributions (e.g. Debian 11) have ceased to provide the boot protocol drivers in their standard kernel. So if a `modprobe usbkbd` as root results in an error indicating that such a module is not available, you might need an alternate/custom kernel with the `CONFIG_USB_KBD` kernel build-time configuration option enabled.